# Change default sql mode

Tags: mysql, global-variables

I am trying to set my Mysql mode using this. It works, but when the server is restarted it defaults back to  `STRICT_TRANS_TABLE, NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`. How can I make it permanent so it stays this way after a restart.

```
set global sql_mode="NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES,STRICT_TRANS_TABLE,
NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

Comment: Put it in your my.cnf (linux) or my.ini (windows)...

Answer (score 0):

Alter your mysql configuration file. The file is called `my.cnf` if in windowzzz look for the `my.ini`

Append the following line to it and restart your mysql engine after

```
   sql-mode="NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES,STRICT_TRANS_TABLE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,
   NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```